# Create User method for Custom Manager Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am following this tutorial (http://musings.tinbrain.net/blog/2014/sep/21/registration-django-easy-way/)
to create a user registration model in Django.

I understand that the class UserManager is overwriting the default User model. However, I do not understand this particular part.

The official Django Documentation doesn't explain what this means - It merely shows the full code.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/

Need some clarification as to what's going on here.

```
user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), is_active=True, **kwargs)
user.set_password(password)
user.save(using=self._db)
```

This is the entire class.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), is_active=True, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, is_active=True, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the user instance in memory.  `self.model` attribute is populated then you instantiate the model manager in the model class:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager() # here the `objects.model` is set to `MyUser`
```

Normalized email means that domain part is lower-cased. `is_active` is `True`, so user can log in.  If any additional fields are passed to `create_user()` as [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) then assign these fields to the created user.

```
user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), is_active=True, **kwargs)
```

Set hashed password.

```
user.set_password(password)
```

Save the user instance into the database.

```
user.save(using=self._db)
```

Comment: Thanks. How does user = self.model work? I also found out that the entire chunk of code is actually found in here - https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Comment: See the updated answer.  And yes, user customization doc uses the real code as the example. In fact built-in `User` model is the custom user model which is compatible with previous versions of django :-)

Comment: Ah okay, i see what you mean. Thanks!